"Зная тебя" нужно ли обособление перед тире?
Решил бы, что издеваешься, но(,) зная тебя(,) — ты вполне можешь говорить всерьез.

Думаю, что правильной будет такая фраза:
Решил бы, что издеваешься, но знаю тебя — ты вполне можешь говорить всерьез.
Пояснение
Сложное предложение с подчинительной и  бессоюзной связью.
Однородные сказуемые: решил бы, но знаю.
Бессоюзная связь обозначена тире, изъяснительные отношения: знаю (что?).
